# Is it necessary to manage transactions in Entity Famework 5? (multiple contexts)

Tags: entity-framework, transactions

in a case where there may be multiple DbContexts within a custom unit of work, would EF5 manage **all** the transactional requirements or is the code below still valid / required? If not, how far can the code be reduced and still provide the same functionality?

```
public void SaveAllChanges()
{
    var transactions = new List<DbTransaction>();

    foreach (var context in this.contexts
        .Where(context => context != null)
        .Select(dbcontext => ((IObjectContextAdapter)dbcontext).ObjectContext))
    {
        context.Connection.Open();

        var databaseTransaction = context.Connection.BeginTransaction();

        transactions.Add(databaseTransaction);

        try
        {
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
        catch
        {
            foreach (var transaction in transactions)
            {
                try
                {
                    transaction.Rollback();
                }
                finally
                {
                    databaseTransaction.Dispose();
                }
            }

            transactions.Clear();

            throw;
        }
    }

    try
    {
        foreach (var transaction in transactions)
        {
            transaction.Commit();
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        foreach (var transaction in transactions)
        {
            transaction.Dispose();
        }

        transactions.Clear();

        foreach (var context in this.contexts
            .Select(dbcontext => ((IObjectContextAdapter)dbcontext).ObjectContext)
            .Where(context => context.Connection.State != ConnectionState.Closed))
        {
            context.Connection.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Assume SQL Server 2008 and above.

Comment: Has something led you to believe there has been a change in this area?

Comment: No, but I was reading about DbContext SaveChanges being wrapped in a transaction anyway, so was wondering whether the above was necessary in its entirety.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must handle transactions yourselves when working with multiple contexts but your code is wrong. If any of your transactions fails during commit you can have part of transactions committed and part of transactions rolled back.

The only valid approach is to use `TransactionScope` and either [manage connections](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/diego/archive/2012/01/26/exception-from-dbcontext-api-entityconnection-can-only-be-constructed-with-a-closed-dbconnection.aspx) for EF manually or live with distributed transactions:

```
var objectContexts = this.contexts
                         .Where(context => context != null)
                         .Select(dbcontext => ((IObjectContextAdapter)dbcontext).ObjectContext))
                         .ToArray();

var transactionOptions = new TransactionOptions { 
    IsolationLevel = IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted 
};
using (var scope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required,
                                        transactionOptions)) {
   Array.ForEach(objectContext, 
                 o => o.SaveChanges(SaveOptions.DetectChangesBeforeSave));
   scope.Complete();
}

Array.ForEach(objectContext, o => o.AcceptAllChanges());
```

[Here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alexj/archive/2009/01/11/savechanges-false.aspx) is described why AcceptAllChanges matters.

Comment: Thank you. The code this came from goes back quite a bit. This info is really helpful.